# How to add icon to react-bootstrap navBar?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap and trying to add an icon to the NavBar

```
      <Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Brand>
          <a href="#">&#9776; React-Bootstrap
          <img src={logo} style={{width:100, marginTop: -7}} />
          </a>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle />
      </Navbar.Header>
```

However, the icon is not positioned properly in the navbar

[image]

And from the official site, i can't find any example of adding icon to the navbar.

Thanks

Comment: This shows up when looking for how to add Profile image to the Dropdown. This Github issue is helpful. The title prop can take a React Element. https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/928

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you will need to add a bit of CSS there.

```
.navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  padding: 7px 14px;
}
```

Check working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3hg89yt/5/)

Depending on your image size you can adjust it for your code

Comment: how i close it on screen click?

Answer (score 1):

It's a dirty hack, but I had the same problem and added a className, 'nav-logo-' to my image and then did the following CSS:

```
.nav-logo {
  float: left !important;
  margin-top: -15px !important;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me now 4 years later xD thanks alot